# Deploying a html file website in heroku

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, heroku

I have build a small website using html, css, bootstrap and javascript files. The home page is index.html. I tried to deploy it to my heroku app (buildpack is nodejs), but everytime is says: App not compatible with buildpack. How can I upload my website there?

This is what it shows:

```
D:\Projects\herokudeploy>git push heroku master Counting objects: 572, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects: 100% (477/477), done. Writing objects: 100% (572/572), 17.28 MiB |
48.00 KiB/s, done. Total 572 (delta 58), reused 570 (delta 57)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: 
    https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static.git
    remote:        More info: 
    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to sobhannwebsite.
    remote:
    To *heroku url address*
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to *heroku url address*
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set up a node application, Heroku will expect you to deploy a node app. Currently I dont think you can just throw in a bunch of HTML and CSS on Heroku and run it. You need a Python, NodeJS, Go etc server for your app to run on.

Answer (score 0):

The [static buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static) you are using requires a `static.json` file to be runnable. That file needs to be at the root of your repository.

You should be able to set the content of that file to an empty hash, `{}`.
The buildpack readme on GitHub gives all the configuration you can set on that file for your static site.